# I am installing abinit 8.10.2 on Ubuntu. How can I correct this error?

Tags: ubuntu

I issued the commands:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install then
make installcheck
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_itfo1-DKuehUSp5iNIf_vxALll5eupx

In `make check` I got these errors:

```
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
cd sources/netcdf-4.1.1 && make check 
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: sources/netcdf-4.1
```

I issued the commands: ./configure, make, make check, make install, then

```
make installcheck https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_itfo1-DKuehUSp5iNIf_vxALll5eupx
```

In `make check` I got these errors:

```
.1: No such file or directory
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
cd sources/atompaw-4.0.1.0 && make check 
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: sources/atompaw-4.0.1.0: No such file or directory
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
cd sources/wannier90-2.0.1.1 && make check 
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: sources/wannier90-2.0.1.1: No such file or directory
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
cd sources/etsf_io-1.0.4 && make check 
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: sources/etsf_io-1.0.4: No such file or directory
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
cd sources/bigdft-1.7.1.25 && make check 
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: sources/bigdft-1.7.1.25: No such file or directory
Makefile:1187: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[2]: [check-local] Error 1 (ignored)
Makefile:4568: recipe for target 'check-local' failed
make[3]: *** [check-local] Error 99
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/tests'
Makefile:4439: recipe for target 'check-am' failed
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/tests'
Makefile:4158: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/tests'
Makefile:2318: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

**In the "make install" i got these errors**:

```
Makefile:3806: recipe for target 'install-binPROGRAMS' failed
make[3]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/src/98_main'
Makefile:4175: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/src/98_main'
Makefile:924: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvester/Desktop/abinit-8.10.2/src'
Makefile:2318: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Then I don't understand why the software fails to install.

Comment: this is the codes. I used "$cd abinit-8.10.2" " $ ./configure"  $make" then  "$ sudo make install" .  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ra1gCy3NNgc_swdTpSEqVsyqBiyhOg5B

Comment: Do you get any errors with `make` or `make install`?

Comment: in the "make check" and "make install"